# Code Igniter giving error Fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I following code is giving me error "Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean"

```
        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);
        if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }
```

Comment: which version of codeigniter you used? I think you have a typo
$query = $this->db->get($this->sess_table_name);

Comment: where are you using this code? library? controller? model? helper?

Answer (score 1):

`Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean` means your query:

```
$this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);
```

is fails due to some error and it returns FALSE, which is the the return type of `select` query in case of failure.

So first of all check what `$this->sess_table_name` contains in it and after that print `RAW QUERY` by using:

```
 $this->db->last_query();
```

and check what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `var_dump` before `if` statement. `$query` must be `false`.

Maybe two reasons:

1. Your database connection is lost.
2. Or, `$this->sess_table_name` is not a valid data table name.